# creating aop pointcut after connect to sqlite database in Spring 3

Tags: android, spring, sqlite, spring-3

Hi im working with spring 3 and sqlite3. The thing is that in sqlite 3 each time a new connection is stablished its neccessarry to activate the pragma foreign_keys for being able to work with foreign keys. So, mi idea is adding a pointcut after the connection is stablished and then execute this query ¨PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;¨ before anything, but the problem is that i dnt know which method of which class stablishes the connection. I thought was the DataSource but obviusly is not. This should be my aspect

```
<aop:config>
<aop:aspect ref= "pragmaDAO">

<aop:after-returning pointcut=
"execution(* org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(..))"
method="initPragmaForeignKeys" />
</aop:aspect>

</aop:config>
```

Just in case, this is my conexion-servlet

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"
    p:dataSource-ref="pool" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    name="transactionManager" p:dataSource-ref="pool" />

<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" name="pool"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}"

    p:maxWait="5000"
            p:initialSize="${initialSize}" p:maxActive="${maxActive}"

     />



</beans>
```

If somebody knows a better way to do this in Spring3, please tell me. Thanks

Comment: Why so complex? A `BasicDataSource` has a property called `connectionInitSqls` just add the SQL to execute into that property. No need to use AOP for that.

Comment: Yes,i was using an old package of dbcp,thanks. Now i m using dbcp2, but when i add the configuration 
    <property name = "connectionInitSqls">
        <list>
            <value>PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON</value>
        </list>
    </property>
throws next error: Bean property 'connectionInitSqls' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Comment: I suggest checking [the javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-2.0.1/index.html) of the classes you use so that you can figure out the correct property name.